# Inexplicably, Recognizably, Specifically - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, steganography

When you blink, you will always blink twice 
*No, that doesn't make sense, does it?* 
You know that without a doubt, the sun rises daily. 
*But what if it is cloudy and you can't see it?* 
Look I won't be surprised if this puzzle is solved early.
*Unless it's harder than I think it is.* 
Carefully but quick, if you wait too long you will be late.
*Late to answering the riddle that is, it's much more satisfying if you solve it first.*

You may wonder if this is all done precisely
*But I promise I haven't gotten that good at puzzles yet.* 
Will it ever make sense to end a sentence with the word the 
*Maybe, or maybe none of this makes sense. Should it?* 
Find out the clues, but know they are not all the same, 
*Or they could all be alike, or they could not be, who knows?* 
That was ironic to say, the person making the puzzle knows, always. 
*Although maybe it's not ironic, it could just be by chance.*

The prior blocks may seem weird, but the clues are unfailing. 
*Ahh, but I could be sneaky and make them useless.* 
Ends and solutions of puzzles are fun, if they're not repetitive. 
*If you pay attention this particular solution should not be hard.* 
Are you aware of what's important or not 
*Punctuation may help, it may not, who knows?* 
Hints are hard to come by, but often hide among letters. 
*The only thing I can tell you for sure, is that only certain things are helpful*

**So. Simple enough right? Tell me what I am.**

Hint:

> A special day relatively changes me, yet I stay the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start:

> The first word of each line that is not in italics gives
>
> 'When you look carefully you will find that the ends are hints'

Now I'm a bit stuck, but

The ends are (assuming still non italics)

> Twice, daily, early, late
> Precisely, the, same, always
> Unfailing, repetitive, not, letters

After being told the answer, here is what that means:

> It is a riddle:
>
> Twice daily. Early. Late.
> *Two 12 hours per day, one set starts early in the morning the other late at night*
> Precisely the same, always.
> *Always 12 months a year, 24 hours a day*
> Unfailing. Repetitive. Not letters.
> *Always 12 months a year, every year, and not letters means it's a number - 12*

We also get the punctuation for this from the last words in each line.

Edit/Answer/Explanation from OP:

> The answer I was going for is the **number 12**. While things like sun/year seem to fit, I was deliberate in hinting at the number 12. Important hints that would tip you off to that include the 3 words in the title are all 12 letters long. The day that "relatively changes it" is daylight savings, this 12th of March. The hint not letters was to indicate I wanted a number.

Comment: 'Twice, daily, early, late
Precisely, the, same, always
Unfailing, repetitive, not, letters'. seems like it's describing the sun, @n_palum could that be right?

Comment: @SamHarrington That's not it no, sorry, but you're right in guessing something as the core of this is a what am I

Comment: @n_palum its not like it says that in the title or anything :P I'm pretty sure I've got the answer from the hint, is it (rot 13) lrne?

Comment: @n_palum [rot 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) is a cipher where each letter is rotated 13 places through the alphabet. It is handy as it can be decoded in the same way. [rot13.com](http://www.rot13.com/) has all the rots. Rot 13 'lrne' gives 'year', which is what I was asking whether the answer was that?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Oh that's a fun one.. another thing to play with when making puzzles :) And no, right track though.. but year does not fit in with one of the hints.. Also as a nudge - punctuation is deliberate

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Since you were the closest I'm just going to explain it and give you the answer - I'll just put it as an edit to your answer to make it easier.

Comment: @n_palum oh ok. What was the punctuation thing?

Comment: The punctuation at the ends of the lines was intentionally done. To try and make you read them as chunks. Twice Daily. Early. Late. Precisely the same always. Unfailing. Repetitive. Not letters. The big one was not letters being one hint to make you think it was not a literal word.

Comment: @n_palum oh I was looking at all the punctuation! I edited to add that. Nice puzzle! Shame I didn't get it

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Thanks, and it's fine, you were close and it wasn't drawing more attention so I figured closing it out would be fine :)